# How to load MS Word file in new instance?

Tags: c#, process, ms-word, command-line-arguments

**I want to load word document in different instance using `Process.Start()` method.**

This is my code.

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = @"D:\MyWordFile.doc";
info.Arguments = "/n"; //I have tried like this but it doesn't work
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = info;
p.Start();
```

ok, I am trying to hold the process until document don't get exited using `p.WaitForExit()` method. It works fine when there is no word application is loaded. if the Word is already loaded in the Task Manager then it throws an error `No process is associated with this object.` I think it is because it is just loading document in existing process. So, I think I can resolve this issue by loading my word document in new Word Instance.

I have also read the [support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210565) document and found some parameters that allows me to load word file in new instance. I have tried `/n` in the `ProcessStartInfo.Argument` property but, it doesn't work. I think i am doing mistake in assigning arguments in the process or assigned invalid argument. I don't know what is the issue here. 
Any help will be appreciated

Thanks & Regard.

Answer (score 2):

`Arguments` parameter is only used when `FileName` is an executable program. When `FileName` parameter is a document file, the command line from the file type association is used (from the Registry) and `Arguments` parameter is ignored.

You need to construct the whole command line:

```
Process.Start("winword", @"/n ""D:\MyWordFile.doc""");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It is working without double quotation when the file name is not containing space ie. `mydoc.doc` but, if the file name is like `my doc.doc` then it takes the each word as a file name. I have also tried with double quotation like `"my word.doc"` but, it loads the document in the same instance even i try to call it from Windows's `Run` command. I am using MS Word 2007. you bring me just closed to it. the `/n` argument wont work with double quotation.